# Why iPad can't open an email with 'open in mail' option?

Tags: ipad, mail.app

I have a stored email (.eml) file that can be downloaded and open with Mail.app on mac.
When I tried to open the same email in iPad, I clicked 'open with mail' to launch mail app, but nothing seems to happen; the mail app doesn't show the downloaded email.

What might be wrong? Do I need to make additional setup for reading emails downloaded somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

.eml is not supported by iOS by default.

You might try an external app like [Klammer](https://itunes.apple.com/app/eml-file-reader/id386777877?mt=8).